# How to use slave agent name as a parameter in jenkins freestyle project

Tags: jenkins, parameters, nodes, agent, slave

There are several slave machines set in our Jenkins and work just fine.

When i create a freestyle project I checked `Restrict where this project can be run` and put there the name of slave agent. Still ok.

All machines are running on Windows, so I use `Execute windows batch command` to write commands.

The problem I haven't been able to solve yet is when I want to use the agent label as a parameter. With pipeline I was able to use it, but with freestyle project?

When I enable `This project is parameterized` and set a string parameter, what Windows command should I use so the name of the slave agent will be passed to Jenkins and it'll run all following commands on given slave?

thank :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the node label plugin? 
 https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin